# Syntax error on PostgreSQL create table without double quotes

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

Trying to create tables without double quoting the name is resulting in a syntax error, only quoting it works:

```
# CREATE TABLE user (
email TEXT,
first_name TEXT,
last_name TEXT,
password TEXT,
plan TEXT,
gender gender
);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE user (
                     ^
# CREATE TABLE "user" (
email TEXT,
first_name TEXT,
last_name TEXT,
password TEXT,
plan TEXT,
gender gender
);
CREATE TABLE
# \dt
        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | user | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

This is on PosgreSQL 9.5.5 shipping with Ubuntu 16.10:

```
PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005, 64-bit
```

I know it's a bad idea to quote names in PostgreSQL but I can't get around this, what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word in many RDBMS including PostgreSQL, so you should either escape it with double quotes `"` or pick another one.

P.S. As this identifier is a table name, it might be a good idea to use `users` instead of `user`.

Comment: Usually you use plural in table names, so the table should be name `users`

Comment: Ah, how couldn't I've thought of that, dammit all.

Comment: I was trying to use Oracle's DBA naming standards. Looks like it won't work.

Comment: btw isnt good idea have a type `gender` and call the fieldname `gender`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, that's an `enum`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: no, usually singular table names are used ;) Because the entity is "User" not "Users"

Comment: @Oxwivi: you can't create a table named `USER` in Oracle either

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, RIP table names in singular tense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For me table isnt an entity, is a list of entities. So always go plural. In C# EntityFramework when you definine an entity  you create a class, but when you read a table you get a `list<class>`

Comment: Psh, can't accept an answer within a minute of posting the question is a royal pain.